# What is the opposite to "adaptive"?

Tags: terminology

In statistics, there are methods that are named with "adaptive", such as "adaptive randomization" in experimental design, and "adaptive learning". What is the word that is opposite to "adaptive", and used in the opposite methods?

Comment: One method is not "opposite" another. That's probably why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: @PeterFlom: Thanks! Is there a word to mean "non-adaptive"?

Comment: If "adaptive" is left off, then it's "non-adaptive" I think

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question: If a phrase includes an adjective like “adaptive”, it makes sense to wonder what distinction is implied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if all uses of the adjective “adaptive” in statistics can be lumped together or if a single word can be used to described “non-adaptive” methods but I think it always implies that some decisions on data collection or experimental design are taken using data collected during the study itself instead of being fully specified in advance.

For example, taking an example from psychometrics, in a traditional test, all items/questions are defined beforehand whereas in “adaptive testing”, answers to early question are used to select later questions and test takers don't see all questions. Since “adaptive testing” is still regarded as a somewhat advanced/complex method, I would describe fixed tests as “traditional tests” (as I in fact did at the beginning of this paragraph).

Comment: The first half of the first sentence is exactly right. In practice "adaptive" also includes methods that adapt automatically e.g. to the shape of the data, even if the automation is built in by design. The word "adaptive" is like "robust" or "exact" in statistics; it is intended positively but quite what the details are will vary. I agree with others that "non-adaptive" is the only obvious antonym.

Comment: There is no contradiction between “automation […] built in by design” and the rest of the sentence. It's very much the case with adaptive testing as well (no-one is picking questions during a test, it's an iterative computer algorithm).

Comment: Glad to think we agree. It's matter of what the "decisions" are, human and conscious and/or automated but pre-planned.

Comment: There is a concept of an adaptive bandwidth for kernel density estimation, and the opposite would be a fixed bandwidth. Adaptive encompasses a specified number of points (no matter how far away) to estimate the density, whereas a *fixed* bandwidth only calculates the density based on a specified distance away from the point. All of these might suggest in this context **fixed** is the opposite of adaptive, although there are likely different examples not in the discussion where this does not fit.